# Sim Authentication

Tags: c#, smartcard, sim-card, lte

I am currently working on a soft phone working on windows, the goal is to be able to make a call from a standard phone number, using a sim card, through VoLTE (Voice over LTE).

Currently I am able to contact the HSS/HLR and receive a 401 Unauthorized with a nonce (According to he standard RFC3310).
This nonce should be given as a input a AKAv1-MD5 algorithm, which will return a new value that can be send to the HSS/HLR and the authorization is done, this can only be done on a sim card. It cannot be done on a computer due to another input to the algorithm which is highly confidential and only known by a sim card.

Therefore, I would like to know how I can interface with a sim card through a sim card reader, send the nonce to the card, and let it calculate the response and return it.

As my project is written in C# it is preferable if some headers for C# exists.

Since I am using VoLTE the sim card must be a USIM, hence the interface must be to a USIM.

I can, if needed get the Ki key from the sim card, because I working together with a telephone operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are (most probably) looking for the `AUTHENTICATE` command as defined in [3GPP TS 31.102](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=1803) (the former variants of the same command were referred to as `RUN GSM ALGORITHM` or `INTERNAL AUTHENTICATE` in the past).

To use it, you must meet some conditions, citing TS 31.102:

> The function is related to a particular USIM and shall not be
>   executable unless the USIM application has been selected and
>   activated, and the current directory is the USIM ADF or any
>   subdirectory under this ADF and a successful PIN verification
>   procedure has been performed (see clause 5).

The selection of the USIM application is described in section *USIM application selection*, some notes:

- EF.DIR file format is specified in [ETSI TS 102 221](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102221/10.00.00_60/ts_102221v100000p.pdf) (originates from ISO 7816-4)
- USIM AID should start with `A00000000900001` (RID=`A0000000090`, PIX=`0001...`) as defined in [ETSI TS 101 220](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101200_101299/101220/12.00.00_60/ts_101220v120000p.pdf)
- For PIN verification the `VERIFY PIN` command should be used as defined in [ETSI TS 102 221](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102221/10.00.00_60/ts_102221v100000p.pdf) (it might be easier to disable PIN at all). Beware that you need to pad the PIN value with `'FF'` bytes, citing:

> PIN and PIN2 are coded on 8 bytes. Only (decimal) digits (0‑9) shall
>   be used, coded in ITU‑T T.50 [5] with bit 8 set to zero. The minimum
>   number of digits is 4. If the number of digits presented by the user
>   is less than 8 then the ME shall pad the presented PIN with 'FF'
>   before sending it to the 3GPP application.

The underlying cryptography is >somewhat< described in [3GPP TS 33.102](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=2262) (probably the section *Authentication and key agreement*).

To actually communicate with the smart card from .NET use [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp). Some example code is [here](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp/tree/master/Examples) and [here](http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.cz/2010/11/pcsc-sample-in-c.html).

---

If you can get the `Ki` and know the correct algorithm then I would strongly recommend using the 'emulation approach' if possible (can't help here -- but see e.g. [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/21400/83375) with some interesting links).

Disclaimer: My hobbyist GSM experience ended several years ago (before 2.5G) so please do validate my thoughts

Good luck -- you will definitely need it!

EDIT>

Osmocom provides a simple tool -- [Osmo-sim-auth](https://osmocom.org/projects/sim-card-related/wiki/Osmo-sim-auth) which performs the authentication -- might be helpful for you.

Comment: I've also been stumbling over Osmo-sim-auth, and it seems to do the job. 

But to be honest i don't know if it is correct anyway. 

It is able to talk to a sim card and calculate some UMTS  credentials, but can i use these for VoLTE authentication (3g authentication isn't enough)?

Comment: @Niva My bet is yes. I went through some specs, but then found [this](http://www.simpletechpost.com/2012/11/aka-digest-authentication-scheme-for.html) article which seems reasonable. From the specs you need to know if you have USIM or ISIM for different identity mapping. (I am on a thin ice now, so please do validate my thoughts)

Comment: The osmo-sim-auth did the job! 

My solution (it not pretty, but it works!):
I use an app called boghe, written i C#, C++ and c.

Comment: The osmo-sim-auth did the job! 

My solution (it not pretty, but it works!): I use an app called boghe, written i C#, C++ and c. 

Boghe receives the nonce (number used once) from the HLR, this is forwarded to osmo-sim-auth (slightly modified) - a python script.

The python script returns 3 keys, IK, CK, and AKARES. These are "put" back into Boghe, which then can generate a "Digest Response", and return it to the p-CSCF and the registration is done.

And for the record, as far as I can see, then 3G and VoLTE sim authentication is the same.